# Storing a password in a web database?

Tags: database, passwords

So, what I'm trying to achieve is the following:
When you enter the site, there is just a password box. If you enter the password that matches the one in the database, it opens a popup windows with more information. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what web server / application are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your problem:

- You need an index page that allows users to login
- To allow users to login, you will need to use either a form (easiest method) or an AJAX request (slightly more difficult method) that contacts some kind of login function. (I will be using PHP in my example, but you can use other languages as you see fit.)
- In the PHP script, you will need to be able to access the database. ([MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) are the currently recommended PHP classes for this.)
- Once you connect to the database, you will need to query the database to get the relevant row from the table.
- Now you'll need to get the data from the row and perform the necessary checks.
- Finally you will need to return some data to the browser so the browser knows what to do next. (Make sure your code is able to answer the following questions: Did the login succeed? What popup window should be opened? What error message should be displayed? What cookies should be set? Etcetera).

There is more to a website login than this, but that's just the general breakdown of your problem.

Here is what I'm going to use in my example for you:
 - I will be using PHP for dynamic server-side scripts
 - I will be using some JavaScript (just vanilla JS, not jQuery or other variants) for AJAX the login request.
*Obviously you can feel free to use something else in your implementation.*

I would first create `index.html` as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!-- Assuming the language is English -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Some Snazzy Title for Login Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/functions.js"></script>
        <!-- Any additional things you want to include in the head of the HTML page -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Table is used here for formatting -->
        <table id="LoginTable" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <!--- Button to call our JavaScript AJAX login function: -->
        <button onclick="AttemptLogin();">Login</button>
        <!--- Include links to things like register, forgot password, and etc. here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As you'll notice, we include an external JavaScript file called `functions.js` which is located in the *resources/js/* subdirectory. So, to include this, you would create a folder called *resources* in the same directory as `index.html` and then you would create a folder called *js* inside of the *resources* folder. After completing that, we're ready to create `functions.js`:

```
/* Credits to Minko Gechev (blog.mgechev.com) for createXMLHttp() (I have made my own modifications to it, though.) */
function createXMLHttp(){
        //If XMLHttpRequest is available then using it
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== undefined) {
        // XMLHttpRequest is a fairly standard class in most browsers for handling AJAX, but
        // it's not defined in all browsers (including IE)
        return new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // User is using Internet Explorer
        // Now we'll try to use an array of various IE XML HTTP types to find the right one:
        var ieXMLHttpVersions = ['Microsoft.XMLHTTP', 'MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', 'Microsoft.XMLHttp'];
        var xmlHttp;

        // Look through the array and try to create the XMLHttp object
        for (var i = 0; i < ieXMLHttpVersions.length; i++) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(ieXMLHttpVersions[i]);
                return xmlHttp;
            } catch (e) {
                // Do nothing with error
            }
        }

        // Despite the fact that ActiveXObject is defined, none of the XMLHttp versions could be
        // successfully created. The browser's JavaScript implementation is unknown and thus we cannot
        // use AJAX for this.
        return null;
    }else{
        // This browser is unknown and it does not support any of the common XML HTTP classes.
        // As such, we will not be able to AJAX for login through this.
        return null;
    }
}

function AttemptLogin(){
    // First we'll get the current timestamp which we'll append to the login link to prevent caching:
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    // Link to POST login data to (with cache-buster):
    var url = "ajax/login_process.php?cachebuster=" + timestamp;
    var username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value);
    var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("password").value);

    var PostRequestData = "u=" + username + "&p=" password";

    var xmlHttp = createXMLHttp();

    if(xmlHttp === null){
        // xmlHttp could not be successfully created
        // Alert the user of this issue and recommend a browser upgrade
        alert("An error occurred that prevented us from logging in.\nThis issue seems to have been caused by your browsers JavaScript implementation. Please consider updating your browser to the newest version or installing a different browser.");
        // Exit the function prematurely
        return;
    } // Else, xmlHttp appears to have been created successfully

    xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Code the callback function which will be executed after the request completes.
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ){
            // It seems like the request successfully executed
            // Now we'll just need to check if the login was successful or not:
            var respText = xmlHttp.responseText;

            if(respText.indexOf("login success") > -1){
                // Now we'll open a popup window here:
                window.open('info.phtml', 'More Information', 'height=400,width=400');
                // Info.phtml will do additional security checks before displaying the information, by the way.
            }else{
                alert("Error: either the username does not exist or the is incorrect for the username provided.\nPlease try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    // Now that we have the request open, the request header is set, and the callback
    // function is defined, we will finally send the actual login request to the login_process.php page:
    xmlHttp.send(PostRequestData);
}
```

Now we'll need to write out the code for `login_process.php`. Before that, though, we need to create this file's directory. So, in the same folder you put your `index.html` file in, you should create a subdirectory called *ajax*. And now we'll write the `login_process.php` file that goes in that folder:

```
<?php
    // Start up a session so we can hold whether the user is logged in or not:
    session_start();

    // To further prevent caching we'll use these headers:
    header("Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", (time() + 2)) . " GMT");
    header("Date: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

    // Make sure the request is valid:
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
        die("Invalid request type");
    }

    // Now let's do the login.
    // First, connect to the database:
    $mysqli = new mysqli("Your database host", "Your database username", "Your database password", "The database name");

    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        die("Failed to connect to database");
    }

    // Next we'll get the request parameters
    $username = $_POST['u'];
    $password = $_POST['p'];

    // Now we need to clean the username so we can search the database for it
    $safeUsername = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username); // Prevents SQL injection

    // Next let's query to see if this username exists:
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE `username`='$safeUsername' LIMIT 1;");

    if($result->num_rows == 0){
        // The username is unknown.
        // Close the database members and die with vague error message
        $result->free();
        $mysqli->close();
        die("fail");
    } // Else, username exists

    // Get this user's salts and password hash:
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // Now that we have the results as a PHP keyed array, we do not need to keep
    // the database open any longer. So we will now close the database connection and
    // free the database-related objects from the memory.
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->close();

    // Now pull out the database provided values to local variables (for convenience):
    $passwordSalt_1 = $row['salt1'];
    $passwordSalt_2 = $row['salt2'];
    $passwordHash = strtolower($row['passHash']); // Hexdigest of users current password hash

    // Hash the users password with the salt and see if the results match:
    $userPasswordData = $passwordSalt_1 . $password . $passwordSalt_2;
    $requestedPassHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $userPasswordData));

    // Now we just need to see if the user's passHash in the database is the same as
    // the hash we just generated via the password sent in the request:
    $isLoggedIn = ($passwordHash == $requestedPassHash);

    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = ($isLoggedIn ? '1' : '0');

    // Send back the login result to the AJAX callback function:
    die(($isLoggedIn ? "login success" : 'fail'));
?>
```

And now all we're left with is coding `info.phtml` (the pop-up webpage):

```
<?php
    // Start up the session so we can access the session variables:
    session_start();

    // We certainly don't want the browser to cache our webpage which should require login:
    header("Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", (time() + 2)) . " GMT");
    header("Date: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

    // Now we'll simply check if the user is logged in by referencing the session:
    if( !isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || // Check if session variable is set
        empty($_SESSION['logged_in']) || // Check if the variable isn't empty
        ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != '1') ){ // Check if the variable is anything other than the valid value

        // If any of the above statements are true, we reach this code and the user is not properly logged in
        // As such, we should display an error page message instead of displaying the page.
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 418 I'm a teapot", true, 418);
        /* Personal Note: I'm using 418 'I'm a teapot' here out of personal preference.
           Technically the RFC has not defined a response code for telling a user that they need
           to login to the website before accessing the page, but sending back a non-4xx response
           does not seem reasonable. 4xx response codes tell the client that there was an error
           with their request. Since this wasn't a server a error and the request did not go over
           successfully, a level 4xx response is the most fitting. */

        die("Error: You need to login before accessing this page.");
    } // Else, the user is logged in. Go ahead and show them the page.
?>
```

Hopefully this helps you with setting up your website. If this does help, please don't forget to upvote. (Not trying to beg, but I did spend quite a while writing up this answer to your question :P) I have not tested the code provided, so I'm sure there might be some minor errors throughout it. Obviously you'll need to rewrite some portions of the code to work with your situation, but overall, it should give you an indepth look at this sort of system can be coded.